# Can an implicit conversion of an implicit value satisfy an implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit-parameters

I'm defining some Scala implicits to make working with a particular unchangeable set of Java classes easier. The following Scala code is a simplified example that obviously looks crazy, in the real world I'm trying to grab particular resources (rather than numeric age) implicitly from the Monkey, Tree & Duck for use in various methods like `purchaseCandles()`:

```
// actually 3 Java classes I can not change:
case class Monkey(bananas: Int) 
case class Tree(rings: Int)
case class Duck(quacks: Seq[String])

// implicits I created to make my life easier...
implicit def monkey2Age(monkey: Monkey): Int = monkey.bananas / 1000
implicit def tree2Age(tree: Tree): Int = tree.rings
implicit def duck2Age(duck: Duck): Int = duck.quacks.size / 100000

// one of several helper methods that I would like to define only once,
// only useful if they can use an implicit parameter.
def purchaseCandles()(implicit age: Int) = {
  println(s"I'm going to buy $age candles!")
}

// examples of usage
{
  implicit val guest = Monkey(10000)

  purchaseCandles()
}

{
  implicit val guest = Tree(50)

  purchaseCandles()
}

{
  implicit val guest = Duck(Seq("quack", "quack", "quack"))

  purchaseCandles()
}
```

The compiler error, which occurs 3 times:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter age: Int 
purchaseCandles()
               ^
```

Leaving aside the many different ways in which this sample code is crazy, my real question is: can implicit conversions of implicit values satisfy implicit parameters in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no. Scala's compiler will only ever look to apply a single implicit, so if it fails to spot an `implicit int` lying around, it will stop and give up.

However, you could write your `purchaseCandles` method to operate on types that can be converted to an `Int`, and require a parameter of that type:

```
def purchaseCandles[A <% Int]()(implicit age : A) = {
  val asAge : Int = age
  println(s"I'm going to buy $asAge candles!")
}
```

The `asAge` part is necessary to force the application of the implicit conversion.

As of yet, I seem to need to specify the type of `A` in this scenario, though I can't work out why: since there shouldn't be other values around of types that can be implicitly converted to `Int` (this happens with brand new types as well, so it's not the ubiquity of `Int`.) But you can do:

```
{
  implicit val guest = Monkey(10000)

  purchaseCandles[Monkey]()
}
```

This use of implicits, however, is probably a bad idea!

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - shame about having to specify the type of A tho.

Comment: View bounds `[A <% Int]` used in this answer are deprecated now, more info here: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do that: You just have to mark the parameters of your implicit conversion as implicit as well:

```
implicit def monkey2Age(implicit monkey: Monkey): Int = monkey.bananas / 1000
implicit def tree2Age(implicit tree: Tree): Int = tree.rings
implicit def duck2Age(implicit duck: Duck): Int = duck.quacks.size / 100000
```

This will chain the implicits they way you want.

As always: Beware, it will also do so in places you don't want it to. By the way, I strongly advise against an implicit parameter of type `Int` (or an implicit value thereof). It is just too generic. (I'm somewhat assuming this is just like that in your example).