# Scala resolution of multiple implicit parameters

Tags: scala, implicits

In trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431278/can-an-implicit-conversion-of-an-implicit-value-satisfy-an-implicit-parameter), I came up with the following code:

```
    case class Monkey(bananas: Int) 
    case class Tree(rings: Int)
    case class Duck(quacks: Seq[String])

    implicit class IntLike(val x : Int) extends AnyVal

    implicit def monkey2Age(monkey: Monkey): IntLike = monkey.bananas / 1000
    implicit def tree2Age(tree: Tree): IntLike = tree.rings
    implicit def duck2Age(duck: Duck): IntLike = duck.quacks.size / 100000

    def purchaseCandles[A <% IntLike]()(implicit age : A) = {
      val asAge : IntLike = age
      println(s"I'm going to buy $asAge candles!")
    }              

    {
        implicit val guest = Tree(50)
        purchaseCandles()
    }
```

Note that the `IntLike` is only there to convince me this wasn't a problem focussed on `Int`.

This seems a fairly standard, if bad, use of implicits, and I was expecting it to work happily. However, on invoking `purchaseCandles()` the REPL yields the following error:

> error: ambiguous implicit values:
>    both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
>    and value guest of type Tree
>    match expected type A

I cannot for the life of me see how this is the case. A is bound to have an view bound of `IntLike`, a type I just invented. The REPL confirms that there is no implicit view available:

> scala> implicitly[Tree => IntLike]
>
> res14: Tree => IntLike = function1

but

> scala> implicitly[scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] => IntLike]
>
> :18: error: No implicit view available from scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String] => IntLike.

So how can `StringCanBuildFrom` be of an appropriate type? Is the compiler capable of resolving the multiple dependent implicits, and if not, why is this the error being shown?

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting an answer, here is first the reduced case. Note that you are calling `purchaseCandles` with no hint whatsoever on type `A` which I think is the origin of the problem.

```
object Foo

def test[A <% Foo.type](implicit bar: A) {}

test
```

Error:

```
<console>:10: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type =>
     scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 and method conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]
 match expected type A
              test
              ^
```

---

The `StringCanBuildFrom` seems more like a confusing error message. If you concentrate on `conforms` here, the reason why this doesn't work might become more clear: `Predef.conform` states that whenever you ask for an implicit conversion `A => A`, this is guaranteed by means of identity. This is so that if you have `def foo[B <% A](b: B)`, you can always call `foo` with a value of type `A` without the need to define any sort of `A => A`.

---

You are asking for the resolution of implicit argument of an *unspecified type* along with a conversion from that *unspecified type* to `IntLike`. I think that is beyond the scope of the implicit resolution algorithm. Still the error message is somewhat strange.

Comment: Yeah, being beyond the scope of implicit resolution seems likely, but the message is confusing. Everything works if you explicitly specify the type parameter: `test[Foo.type]` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Still no explanation why it fails—although, as said, I expect this is too much for the implicit resolution because of the undefined input type—, but you can make it work like this:

```
    implicit def findIntLike[A <% IntLike](x: A): IntLike = x
    def purchaseCandles()(implicit age: IntLike) = {
      println(s"I'm going to buy $age candles!")
    }              

    implicit val guest = Tree(50)
    purchaseCandles()
```